# What is the correct format to use with joda time datetime formatter in Mirth?

Tags: jodatime, mirth

In one of the HL7 date time values, I get values like `202009010935-0400` I am trying to use joda time to parse that and convert into a `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format. Using this line of code

```
var instant = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern('yyyyMMddHHmm-ZZZZ').parseMillis(new String(date));
var value = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss).print(instant);
```

throws an exception

`JavaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "202009010935-0400" is malformed at "-0400"`

Since I have no control over the data value sent, what's the correct format to use in this case?

I have tried using `yyyyMMddHHmm-HHmm` but that simply converts the date to `2020-09-01T04:00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the pattern, `yyyyMMddHHmmZ` and do as follows:

**Demo:**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "202009010935-0400";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmZ").withOffsetParsed();
        DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTimeStr);
        System.out.println(dateTime);    
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-01T09:35:00.000-04:00
```

Check [`DateTimeFormat`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to learn more about the patterns.

**Note:** Check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Using the `java.time` (JSR-301) API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "202009010935-0400";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmZ");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-01T09:35-04:00
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.